# How to import Instagram stickers into spark ar?

Tags: facebook, spark-ar-studio

I want create Instagram effect with spark ar. How can I use stickers like "STAY HOME","@MENTION", "#HASHTAG"?

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of Spark there is a "2D Sticker" template - this should be a good starting point for what you are trying to do.

[image]